# How to set width and height of the focus region with Android CameraX?

Tags: android, android-camerax

Does anyone know if there is any way to set width and height of the focus region with Android CameraX?

I was succefully set the position of focus point with MeteringPoint. As I know by default, the member variable **size** of MeteringPoint is used to calculate the metering rectangle

```
metering rectangle width = size * sensorSizeOrCropRegion.width 
metering rectangle height = size * sensorSizeOrCropRegion.height
```

Or if there is no way to do that by using CameraX directly, then is it possible to the camera2 interop APIs?

But I want to have a metering rectangle with, let say 50dp width and 50dp height. How can I do that?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you want to set an overlay (like a focus View , like we have in our native camera application ) where the user has clicked ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. But no. I want to set the metering rectangle for auto-focus (the width and height of the focus region)

Answer (score 0):

```
val factory: MeteringPointFactory = SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory(
                previewView.width.toFloat(), previewView.height.toFloat())
val autoFocusPoint = factory.createPoint(PointX, PointY, size)
```

From the doc string of method `createPoint(x, y, size)`:

> Size is the size of the MeteringPoint width and height(ranging from 0
> to 1). It is the (normalized) percentage of the sensor width/height
> (or crop region width/height if crop region is set).

then;

```
camera.cameraControl.startFocusAndMetering(
    FocusMeteringAction.Builder(
      autoFocusPoint,
      FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF
     ).build()
)
```